# DNSMASQ on Ubuntu in VM not offering leases to client

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, dnsmasq

I have Ubuntu running in VMWare workstation 12. I have a USB ethernet adapter which appears as eth1, and is statically assigned 192.168.0.10

My `dnsmasq.conf` is:

```
port=0
domain-needed
bogus-priv
server=8.8.8.8
interface=eth1
no-hosts
no-resolv
dhcp-host=60:9e:29:f5:c6:b1,192.168.0.31,24h
#dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.99,12h
```

I have alternated between the dhcp-range option, and tesing with the dhcp-host option for a specific client. Neither makes any difference.

Listening with `tcpdump -i` on eth1, I see the following:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:23:03.845805 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 60:9e:29:f5:c6:b1 (oui Unknown), length 300
22:23:05.550081 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 60:9e:29:f5:c6:b1 (oui Unknown), length 300
22:23:07.354164 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 60:9e:29:f5:c6:b1 (oui Unknown), length 300
```

Syslog does not reveal errors, and shows `dnsmasq` thought the syntax was fine. The service is confirmed to be running. Network manager is disabled.

WHat else could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have at least one `dhcp-range` entry to enable dhcp at all. You can use

```
dhcp-range=::,static
```

if you are only serving the one IP address. Add `log-dhcp` for some debug.